# How to copy link which is declared in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Actually I want, I declare a link in javascript. And copy the link using a button.

I'm trying this. But it's showing error.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#copy-button").click(function() {
        var copyLink = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
        copyLink .select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
      });
    });
```

```css
  body {
      padding: 20px;
    }
```

```html
 <script>  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <button type="button" id="copy-button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"> <span class="fa fa-copy"> </span> Copy </button>
```

I'm trying this, but not work : [Copy to clipboard with Rails and Javascript via a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547210/copy-to-clipboard-with-rails-and-javascript-via-a-link)

Comment: `document.execCommand("copy");` is the same as pressing cntrl-c with an input/dropdown/etc selected

Comment: Ohh then how to do it? I want I declared the link in the javascript and copy this link. @freedomn-m

Comment: @Dev this answer has already been provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/1886206

Comment: There are numerous existing questions, some with very detailed answers and explanations.  Essentially you have to create a control, put the text in the control, copy, remove the control.  Here's a detailed solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34192073/2181514

Comment: Hmm OK I'll follow this.